# How can I get Capistrano to deploy without prompting for a password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

When I run `cap deploy` at a certain point towards the end of the process, I get a password prompt...

```
 ** keeping 5 of 6 deployed releases
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' rm -rf /opt/deployed_rails_apps/myapp/releases/20120922200242"
    servers: ["myhost.com"]
    [username@myhost.com] executing command
Password:
```

Is there a way I can get it to complete without prompting me to enter a password?

Here's my `deploy.rb`...

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

require "rvm/capistrano"

set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.3-p194@run_passenger'

set :rvm_type, :user

set :application, 'myapp'

set :repository, 'git@github.com:fakename/myrepository.git'

set :deploy_to, "/opt/deployed_rails_apps/#{application}"

set :scm, "git"
set :branch, "master"

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :keep_releases, 5
after "deploy:update", "deploy:cleanup"

load 'deploy/assets'

role :app, 'username@myhost.com'
role :web, 'username@myhost.com'

namespace :deploy do

  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "touch #{current_release}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  task :stop, :roles => :app do
    # Do nothing.
  end

  desc "Restart Application"
  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    run "touch #{current_release}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your deployment user has appropriate permissions and you don’t need to use `sudo`, you can set `:use_sudo` to false and Capistrano won’t use it.

Just add

```
set :use_sudo, false
```

to your `deploy.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your SSH public key on the machine you're deploying to.  This isn't a Capistrano thing.  [Here's one guide](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html).  There are many others that you can find with a quick search.

Comment: Thanks, but look a little more closely at the output.

Comment: BTW, I have ssh keys set up on all three systems involved.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need root permission in order to delete files under /opt/deployed_rails_apps/myapp/releases/ then you can edit the /etc/sudoers file to allow your deploy user to use sudo without the password.

But I suspect the answer by @matt using `set :use_sudo, false` should take care of your problem.